# Consecutive relative clauses referring to one object

Tags: relative-clauses

Consider

> Today I finished reading a book, titled "Fifteen Dogs", written by (the?) Canadian writer André Alexis, which has been / was published in 2015.

All relative clauses refer to the book. Is it a natural and correct way? Or should I rephrase the sentence

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, having "the" in front of Canadian writer is entirely optional.

You should say "was published," the past tense, rather than "has been published," the perfect, here.

As a native English speaker, I understood immediately that you were referring to the book, but I think it might even be better to do something like this:

> Today I finished reading a book, titled "Fifteen Dogs" by Canadian writer André Alexis, which was published in 2015.

An even better way to do this would be this:

> Today I finished reading *Fifteen Dogs,* a book by Canadian author André Alexis, which was published in 2015.

Or you could try splitting it into two sentences.  There are many ways to do this.